# Run windows service on a specific time

Tags: c#, windows

Can a windows service be set to run at a specific time..?

Example

```
From 8:00 am to 5:00pm run process 
From 5:00 pm to 8:00am run process
```

This process can run daily, weekly or a single day..

Please let me know, your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar situation where I had to develop a service which would do something only during trading time which is from 11:00 am to 3:00 pm everyday in that specific case. It would remain idle the rest of the day. I am sharing what I did in my case. I am not sure whether it would be helpful for you but I hope that it will be.

Two variables maintaining the starting time and ending time

```
TimeSpan StartingTime = new TimeSpan(
                             Int32.Parse(
                               ConfigurationManager
                                  .AppSettings["StartingTimeHour"]), 
                             Int32.Parse(
                               ConfigurationManager
                                   .AppSettings["StartingTimeMinute"]), 0);
TimeSpan EndingTime = new TimeSpan(
                             Int32.Parse(
                               ConfigurationManager
                                   .AppSettings["EndingTimeHour"]), 
                             Int32.Parse(
                               ConfigurationManager
                                   .AppSettings["EndingTimeMinute"]), 0);
//Starting time and Ending time may change in future. So I used app.config 
//instead of fixing them to (11,0,0) and (15,0,0) respectively
```

A method to check whether it is trading time

```
public bool TradingTime()
{                        
    TimeSpan CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    return ((CurrentTime > StartingTime) && (CurrentTime < EndingTime));            
}
```

Then where it is necessary to check the time and execute something depending on that:

```
while (TradingTime())
{
    //do whatever required
}
```

Comment: You could you `Int32.TryParse(string, out int)` method for converting a string to an integer. `Int32.Parse` method will throw an exception if the string is not properly formatted, if it's argument is null or if the string contains a large integer. But `Int32.TryParse` will not through an exception in this case. It will return `false` if the string couldn't be converted to integer, otherwise it will return `true` and the second parameter will then contain the integer value.

Comment: However, if you need to handle all of the above mentioned exception cases by yourself, then you can use `Int32.Parse` method wrapped with appropriate `try...catch` blocks and show appropriate messages for them.

Comment: Thanks @Sayem, You may edit my answer and put `Int32.TryParse(string, out int)` instead of `Int32.Parse` method.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, if this is your requirement, you would be better served by writing a simple console application, and then using the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to schedule it as needed.

This will provide the same benefits as a service, but allow you a lot more control over scheduling after deployment.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the quick reply.. All suggestion looks great.. But before i start i want to share with you the scenario of my application.. The program will run by 24/7 * Scenario number 1 From 8:00 am to 5:00 pm the application will check several folders and scan them, if the folder contain some files.. the program will create an email attaching all the files and will be send to user A * Scenario number 2 From 5:00 pm to 8:00 am the same process will be executed but a different user Using this scenario, can i use your suggestion..?

Comment: @link It depends - if you want the service to just watch a folder continuously, then it'd be better to use a `FileSystemWatcher` in a service and just watch it continuously.  If you want to have it run at regular times, then Task Scheduler is a good option, as it lets you easily change the schedule...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to go about this.  The easiest from a coding perspective is to write a console application and then run it using the task scheduler.

A windows service is always running, so you would want your service to sleep for some amount of time, wake up check if the current time is in the window, and if it is then execute.

Both approaches have their pros and cons, and it's really more about what the service does.  One question I don't know the answer to is whether scheduled tasks run if the user that scheduled the task isn't logged in.  This would be my biggest concern regarding the task scheduler approach.

Comment: Hi Guys, 


   Thanks for the quick reply.. All suggestion looks great.. But before i start i want to share with you the scenario of my application.. The program will run by 24/7  

* Scenario number 1
     From 8:00 am to 5:00 pm the application will check several folders and scan them, if the folder contain some files.. the program will create an email attaching all the files and will be send to user A 

* Scenario number 2 
     From 5:00 pm to 8:00 am the same process will be executed but a different user 

  Using this scenario, can i use your suggestion..?

Comment: if it's different users i think you really want to go with scheduled tasks.  otherwise you are going to open up a whole can of worms about managing identity -- it will get ugly fast.

Comment: you can thank me by up voting my answer and/or marking it as the answer.

Comment: Already did that.. i think.. i click yes to this question "was this post useful to you..?"

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the Windows Task Scheduler and create a task to start the services, and another task to stop the services. All you need to do is create a batch file to start and stop the services.

Example Start Service:

```
net start MyService
```

Example Stop Service

```
net stop MyService
```